# fatal: remote error: CAPTCHA required - Bitbucket - Powershell Script

Tags: c#, git, powershell, bitbucket

I wants to checkout the branch and commit the code changes using powershell script. This powershell script will be called from c# code.

But some times i'm getting the following issue

> fatal: remote error: CAPTCHA required Your Bitbucket account has been
>   locked.  To unlock it and log in again you must solve a CAPTCHA. This
>   is typically caused by too many attempts to login with an incorrect
>   password.  The account lock prevents your SCM client from accessing
>   Bitbucket and its mirrors until it is solved, even if you enter your
>   password correctly.

If i logout in browser and login again by entering the CAPTCHA it is working fine. But if i host my application on server and if issue occurs, Logging out and login again is not the proper fix.

Can you please suggest good approach of handling this issue.

My Powershell code for Cloning the branch:

```
param(
    [parameter(position=0)]
    [string]$checkoutDirectory,

    [parameter(position=1)]
    [string]$checkoutBranch
)

function CheckoutTheCode($checkoutRepoUrl, $checkoutDirectory, $checkoutBranch)
{
    [hashtable]$Return = @{}
    try
    {
        if(Test-Path -Path $checkoutDirectory )
        {
            Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $checkoutDirectory
        }

        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $checkoutDirectory

        # Cloning
        git clone --single-branch -b $checkoutBranch $checkoutRepoUrl $checkoutDirectory

        $Return.Branch = $checkoutBranch
        $Return.Directory = $checkoutDirectory
        $Return.Status = $true
        $Return.Message = "Success"
    }
    catch
    {
        $Return.Message = $Error[0].Exception
        $Return.Status = $false
    }

    Return $Return 
}
```

My Powershell code for Commit changes:

```
param(
    [parameter(position=0)]
    [string]$checkoutDirectory,

    [parameter(position=1)]
    [string]$commitMessage
)

function CommitTheCode($checkoutDirectory, $commitMessage)
{
    [hashtable]$Return = @{}
    try
    {
        cd $checkoutDirectory
        git add .
        git commit -m $commitMessage
        git push

        $Return.Status = $true
        $Return.Message = "Success"
    }
    catch
    {
        $Return.Message = $Error[0].Exception
        $Return.Status = $false
    }

    Return $Return 
}

CommitTheCode $checkoutDirectory $commitMessage
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following steps worked for me (without asking a Bitbucket admin to click a button)

For Windows,

1. go to the credential manager (you can find this by searching for it in Start menu)
2. remove all credentials related to your bitbucket account
3. try again with your script.